# Update SnapKit Constraint offset

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, snapkit

I am using [SnapKit](http://snapkit.io/docs/) and can't find a clean way to update the offset of a constraint. It's a simple loading bar view whose inner view (expiredTime) has to fill the parent (left to right) according to percentage.

I create the constraint in the `awakeFromNib` of a custom UIView

```
    self.expiredTime.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(self)
        make.top.equalTo(self)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self)
        self.constraintWidth = make.width.equalTo(self).constraint 
    }
    setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```

then whenever the time is updated i call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` which will trigger the default updateConstraints() which has been overloaded as by apple hint:

**Does not work:** (the expiredTime view always fit with the parent view)

```
override func updateConstraints() {

    let offset = self.frame.width * CGFloat(percentage)

    self.expiredTime.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(self).offset(offset).constraint
    }
    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

This also **does not work**:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    let offset = self.frame.width * CGFloat(percentage)
    self.constraintWidth?.update(offset: offset)
    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

Rebuilding all the constraint **works** but i would like to avoid it

```
override func updateConstraints() {

    self.expiredTime.snp.remakeConstraints() { (make) in
        make.left.equalTo(self)
        make.top.equalTo(self)
        make.bottom.equalTo(self)
        self.constraintWidth = make.width.equalTo(self).multipliedBy(self.percentage).constraint
    }
    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your first solution does not work, because you already set the `width` of your expiredTime view to the full width before adding the offset. To make it work you have to set the width to `0` and then add the offset. But the offset is not really needed here, you can simply set the width to the calculated width:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    let width = self.frame.width * CGFloat(percentage)
    self.expiredTime.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(width)
    }
    super.updateConstraints()
}
```

**Or** if you keep a reference to the constraint you don't have to override `updateConstraints()` at all. You can simply call the constraint's `update` method (without calling `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` afterwards)

```
constraintWidth?.update(offset: CGFloat(percentage) * view.bounds.width)
```

Just remember to set the width to `0` when you initialize `constraintWidth`:

```
self.expiredTime.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.top.bottom.equalTo(self)
    self.constraintWidth = make.width.equalTo(0).constraint 
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, the actual problem lies on how the SnapKit search and update the already-made constraints. if you make the constraint y=ax, and update it with y=ax+b, it will not match when searching, that's why you must add `.offset(0)` chain. It will cause a pattern match when updating, or it will fail.

Comment: @Neal.Marlin yes it was more clear to me once i understood what uniquely identifies a constraint is the views it is connnected with + the operator + the multiplier (at least), but not the offset. And that the `update{}` matches the update constraints with the ones created in the `create{}` (and not the ones created with vanilla API !!) .

Comment: @jalone Yeah, that’s it. : )

Comment: I need this solution so much! Updating constraint constants is not easily achievable without snap kit :]